# Что делает запись "<p metrikaid_длинный_непонятный_код="какой-нибудь id"/>"?

Tags: html, вёрстка, яндекс-метрика

Подскажите, что создаёт теги вида:

```
<p metrikaid_длинный_непонятный_код="какой-нибудь id" />
```

В основном коде сайта. Думал, что яндекс метрика или гугл аналитика, брал их скрипты, обновил - всё равно! Дело в том, что этот тег в IE8 по какой-то причине стал обрамлять тег `<form>` вот так:

```
<P metrikaId_0.42861152486845566="16">
<FORM id=chronoform_callgager class=Chronoform method=post name=callgager action=index.php?option=com_chronoforms&amp;chronoform=callgager&amp;event=submit isValid="true" metrikaId_0.42861152486845566="17"><SPAN class=callH>Вызов специалиста-замерщика</SPAN> </P>
```

И на сайте из-за этого едет вёрстка. Ничего не могу поделать! Если кто сталкивался или просто имеет умную мысль - поделитесь!

Comment: похоже на Яндекс метрику

Answer (score 1):

Joomla?

Ковыряйте темплейты либо самой джумлы, либо расширения chronoform.

Comment: А еще не плохо было бы проверить уязвимости, может быть у вас было внедрение вредоносного кода. Вообщем сомневаюсь, что оно имеет отношщение к яндексу :)

Comment: Спасибо! Буду копать )